# Transform array attribute in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a plain array in JavaScript:

```
$scope.myArray = [{ "coords" : { "lat" : 0, "long" : 0 } }, { "coords" : { "lat" : 1, "long" : 1 } }, { "coords" : { "lat" : 2, "long" : 2 } }];
```

Then, I have the angular-google-maps module, to draw these points as paths to the screen.

```
<ui-gmap-google-map center='map.center' zoom='map.zoom'>
    <ui-gmap-polyline path="myArray" stroke="p.stroke" visible='p.visible' geodesic='p.geodesic' fit="false" editable="p.editable" draggable="p.draggable" icons='p.icons'>
    </ui-gmap-polyline>
</ui-gmap-google-map>
```

This directive, however, expects path to by an array of positions, like this:

```
$scope.myArray = [{ "lat" : 0, "long" : 0 }, { "lat" : 1, "long" : 1 }, { "lat" : 2, "long" : 2 }];
```

Is there any way to simply transform between my first array to the one the ui-gmap-polyline expects? I was thinking about writing a filter, but I'm not sure if that's the best way. Positions will be added (and possibly changed) to myArray, and I want the Google Map to update along with this. Another way would be to watch myArray for changes and create a new array every time to feed to the Map, but there seems to be a very simple solution I'm missing.

`e.g.: path="myArray | filter:coords"`
-> is there any way to filter an array to only return certain fields of each element?

Edit: myArray is a synchronised $firebaseArray (https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-firebasearray). This array is updated by the Firebase API automatically when the backend is updated (out of my control).

Comment: This being a Firebase array makes all the difference. What kinds of changes to your dataset can you expect? Is it append-only? Will existing coords be modified?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [**map**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```
arr.map(function(e) { return e.coords; });
```

**Demo**

```js
var arr = [{
  "coords": {
    "lat": 0,
    "long": 0
  }
}, {
  "coords": {
    "lat": 1,
    "long": 1
  }
}, {
  "coords": {
    "lat": 2,
    "long": 2
  }
}];

arr = arr.map(function(e) {
  return e.coords;
});

console.log(arr);
document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(arr, 0, 2);
```

```html
<pre id="output"></pre>
```

Comment: Was just about to suggest this.

Comment: methinks simplest: `arr.map(function(el){ return e.coords; })`

Comment: Thanks! This function always returns a new array, however. Is there any way to integrate this with the _memoize function to avoid digest errors (Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached.)?

Comment: @FlockDawson Try `$scope.myArray = $scope.myArray.map(function(e) { return e.coords; });`

Comment: @FlockDawson Don't assing the array directly to the scope, first map it and then assing to the scope

Comment: @Tushar Yes, it does work then. But this has the disadvantage that updates are not persisted. The original array is a synchronised $firebaseArray, which get updated when the backend is updated.